# Using pointers to functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function-pointers, javascript-objects

Why is my code only working for object2?

```
function object1() {
    this.URL = "yahoo.com";
    this.getURL = function() { return this.URL; };
}

var object2 = new Object();
object2.URL = "gmail.com";
object2.getURL = function() { return this.URL; };

var sources = new Array();
sources[0] = object1;
sources[1] = object2;
i=0;

var source1 = sources[0];
console.log(source1.getURL());

var source2 = sources[1];
console.log(source2.getURL());
```

If I try to get the URL out of object1, I get this error:
TypeError: source1.getURL is not a function

I am trying to handle multiple HTTP connection, which use different URLs and each one returns a different XML that I have to parse.
I want to do this by creating an Array of objects and do a for each of them, get the URL and connect to it.

Comment: How do you intend to get a pointer in Javascript?

Comment: Assigning to a variable or array the reference to an object or function. I as have done with C language.

Comment: You seem to be under the mistaken impression that because C has a feature, Javascript must also have that feature, overlooking the fact that _they are two different languages_. In fact, Javascript does **not** expose the concept of pointers or references. At all.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I was just trying to see if I can do it with javascript, not really knowing if it was doable at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do

```
var source1 = new sources[0]();
```

in order to instantiate a new object1.

Otherwise source1 points to the function object which has no such member as getURL

EDIT:
You can also do `sources[0] = new Object1();` but I assume this would not work well with the design you're going for (new Objects in array)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. I tryed with Vote Up and said that I have not enough reputation points. But it worked for "Was this post useful to you?". Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Because object1 is a function, you have to create an instance of object1.

This will work

```
var sources = new Array();
sources[0] = new object1();
sources[1] = object2;
```